# Redefine encoding to input custom characters using inputenc

Tags: input-encodings, mapping

I want to reassign different values to characters so that, e.g., when I type a '¤', an 'l' gets output into the pdf file.

To achieve this, I use the `inputenc` package and modify one of its `*.def` files where characters that the user inputs from the keyboard are mapped to characters that will be printed in the output.

Here is the MWE which I compile with `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
¤¦
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I use the `latin1` encoding. I modified the corresponding `latin1.def` file as follows:

```
...
...
\DeclareInputText{164}{l}
\DeclareInputText{166}{i}
...
...
```

This means that slots 164 and 166, which correspond to the characters "¤" and "¦" in the Latin-1 table (see the [ASCII / ISO 8859-1 table spec](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html)), respectively, are to be replaced with plain "l" and "i".

The result, however, is this:

[image: ÂlÂi]

Why do the offending "Â"s get into my document and how to get rid of them?

Comment: Your file is utf8 encoded, not latin1. And don't modify the original def-files.

Comment: Changing input file's encoding to `latin1` helps. I actually copied the original file from `inputenc`s folder structure and modified a copy locally.

Comment: There is no reason to call your modified file `latin1.def` and 1001 reasons not to call it that. Call it `foobar.def` then use `\usepackage[foobar]{inputenc}`

Comment: your example was remapping some little used characters but in the text of your question you said  you wanted to map "0, an a"  If you  redefine digits like 0 essentially everything will break, you will not to be able to set any lengths or counters.

Comment: The "`0` to `a`" was just an example, though I agree, maybe not the best one. I understand that digits are best left as is, so I chose some more rarely-used characters.

Comment: @Rokas but you should edit the question to make it clear what you want, You basically can not redefine _any_ of the ascii range below 128 via this method, you can define a _new_ input encoding by specifying a mapping for characters 128-255.  So as the question is now it is very hard to answer.

Answer (score 3):

The presence of Â in the printout is a clue that your file is actually UTF-8 encoded.

If I save this example file

```
% -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\DeclareInputText{164}{l}
\DeclareInputText{166}{i}

\begin{document}
¤¦
\end{document}
```

(the top line is for telling Emacs I *really* want the file to be Latin-1/ISO8859-1 encoded, your editor may have a similar trick) and compile it, I get

[image]